# HTML5shiv only works when in HEAD section?

Tags: javascript, html

In order to keep my sites as fast as possible, I prefer loading .js scripts at the end of the document, just before the closing body tag, reserving css for the HEAD section. However, I've found that the html shiv code below apparently only works when instantiated in the HEAD section.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Anyone know of a workaround?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The way the HTML5 shiv works **requires** you to put it in the `<head>` element. In fact, it says so in the [project page](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv):

> To use this script, it must be included before the `<body>` element (i.e. in the `<head>`) but doesn't matter if it appears before or after the CSS - but for the sake of performance, it would make better sense to include the CSS first then this script.

This is so IE can recognize the HTML5 elements before it starts constructing the document body.

There is no workaround for this.

The lesson here is not to obsess over putting all your scripts at the end of the page. A CDN is pretty darn quick at serving stuff, so you shouldn't need to move this particular script.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>But as others have mentioned, since Google Code isn't actually a CDN, you should pick another source.</sub>

Comment: Thanks BC, just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something.

Comment: I missed this part as well, moved it into the head tags and everything worked perfectly in IE8.

Answer (score 19):

Google code is **NOT** a CDN. Don't link files in trunk.

Look at the response headers :

[image: Google code is NOT a CDN]

Cache expires after **3 minutes**... it's the exact opposite of what we want from a CDN.

Please stop doing that.

> **Note**
>
> As João Cunha commented, you can find real CDN links on cdnjs.com: [html5shiv](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/html5shiv). ([respond.js](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/respond.js) can be found there as well)

Sample:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: A beautiful answer on SO.  I just came across 10+ links for googlecode html5shiv, and had no clue it expired so quickly.

Comment: If anyone is confused by this answer, like I was initially, I'm guessing this is intended to be supplementary to the accepted answer, since on its own it seems to be answering a different question altogether. (I'm not sure why respond.js is mentioned, though.)

Comment: I mentionned respond.js because these both scripts are the classical combo

Comment: maybe W3C should fix this page too (seem to be a wiki but haven't tried if it allows changes) - https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML5_Shiv (after all those google urls suggested in articles and sites all over the net are now broken)